# How to create new field in a model with initial data from another field?

Tags: django, migration, django-south

In my Django app I have a model like the following:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  ...
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  ...
```

Here `user` is from `django.contrib.auth.models`. I'm using South for migrations and I want to extend `Foo` with a new boolean field with the initial data equal to the `is_active` field in in the `User` model contained in `Foo`'s user field.

Comment: Tried `new_bool = models.BooleanField(default=self.user.is_active)`?

Comment: But that'd affect all future created instances as well right? I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [Data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)

1. Do a schema migration first: add `is_active` field to `Foo` class.

   ```
   # edit your appnames/models.py
   python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto 
   python manage.py migrate appname
   ```
2. Do a data migration:

   ```
   $ python manage.py datamigration appname copy_is_active
   ```
3. Edit `appname/migrations/0???_copy_is_active.py`, especially `forwards` method to do what you want.

   For example,

   ```
   ....
   from appname.models import Foo

   class Migration(DataMigration):
       def forwards(self, orm):
           for obj in Foo.objects.all():
               obj.is_active = obj.user.is_active
               obj.save()
           #for yn in (True, False):
           #    Foo.objects.filter(user__is_active=yn).update(is_active=yn)
   ...
   ```
4. Execute the migration

   ```
   $ python manage.py migrate appname
   ```

Comment: I somehow missed the data migration part of the documentation :) Thanks a lot!